# Sonata Admin configureListFields

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

is it possible to make a custom query in sonataadmin in configureListFields ? .

in this function :

`protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
         $listMapper
            ->>add(....
        ;
    }`

thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override `createQuery` method like this ([source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonata-users/HHQJeRAcK6Q)):

```
public function createQuery($context = 'list') 
{ 
    $query = parent::createQuery($context); 
    // this is the queryproxy, you can call anything you could call on the doctrine orm QueryBuilder 
    $query->andWhere( 
        $query->expr()->eq($query->getRootAlias().'.username', ':username') 
    ); 
    $query->setParameter('username', 'test'); // eg get from security context 
    return $query; 
}
```

AFAIK, you cannot change `SELECT` part of the query and you cannot use `GROUP BY`, because internally Sonata runs this query at least two times. First, it checks how many rows query returns. Second, it runs this query paginated.

Comment: kind of a related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24450039/how-to-customize-configuredatagridfilters-in-sonata-admin-to-use-non-related-mon)?

Answer (score 0):

As Tautrimas said, you can override the `createQuery($context = 'list')` function in your admin class.

You can try to change the SELECT part of the query like this :

```
$query = parent::createQuery($context);
$query->add('select', 'm', false );
$query->add('from', 'Toto\MyBundle\Entity\MyEntity m', false );
```

The third parameter in the add function is a boolean to choose either to append or to replaces the query part.