# How to customize configureDatagridFilters in Sonata Admin to use non related mongodb documents

Tags: mongodb, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, doctrine-mongodb

In my Mongodb I got a **passenger** document, this is a typical item:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("51efdf818d6b408449000002"),
    "createdAt" : 1374674817,
    "phone" : "222222",
    ..
}
```

I also have a **device** document that references a **passenger** document, here is an example:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("51efdf818d6b408449000001"),
    "os" : "android.gcm",
    "passenger" : ObjectId("51efdf818d6b408449000002"),
    ..
}
```

so in other words.. there is no way I can find out the **device** belonging to a **passenger** by running a query on passenger.. it must be a query on device.

In my **PassengerAdmin.php** I got this configure list field definition:

```
public function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->addIdentifier('name', 'text', array('label' => 'Name'))
        ->addIdentifier('phone', 'text', array('label' => 'Phone #'))
        ->addIdentifier('createdAt', 'datetime', array('label' => 'Created At'))
        ->addIdentifier('device.os', 'text', array('label' => 'Device OS Type')) 
        ..
    ;
}
```

which works fine (I have no idea how sonata managed to map `device.os` to passengers.. but oh well).

Inside my configureDataGridFilters this will return an error:

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagrid)
{
    $datagrid->add('device.os');
}
```

error:

> Notice: Undefined index: device.os in
>   ../vendor/sonata-project/doctrine-mongodb-admin-bundle/Sonata/DoctrineMongoDBAdminBundle/Builder/DatagridBuilder.php
>   line 60

which i guess makes sense.. and even if i created that index nothing will be returned.. (by the way I got that idea from [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:jSlZshJexdgJ:sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/list_field_definition.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk): see displaying subentity properties

**question:**

how can I customize the filter regarding the device OS version so that it incorporates info related to the Device document. lemme show what I want to get done using this example (mix of code and pseudocode):

```
->add('osVersion', 'doctrine_mongo_callback', [
    'callback' => function ($queryBuilder, $alias, $field, $params) {
            if ($params['value'] === null) {
                return;
            }
            // for each passengers as passenger
            // get passenger.id = %passengerID%
            // grab device that has passenger = %passengerID%
            // filter so that device.os == $params['value']

    'field_type' => 'choice',
    'field_options' => ['choices'=> ['android.gcm'=> "Android", "os.ios"=>"iOS"]]
]);
```

I noticed that the `createQuery` method of the superclass `Admin` can be [overridden](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19213894/766570).. but it seems that that is globally so, and it wouldn't help me in this specific case.